# What's the difference between jsr_w and wide instructions in Java bytecode?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

According to the Java byte code specification 9, the `wide` instruction modifies the behavior of another instruction. Thus, an instruction can extend the size of certain input data, say for example, the indexes into the constant pool. But then, the specification also provides the jsr_w. **What is the main difference between `jsr_w` and using `wide` `jsr` in conjunction?**

Comment: Have you got a link to "jsr_wide"? I can't seem to find it. There's a "jsr_w" instruction, but that's a jump subroutine with a wide index already (hence taking 4 branch bytes rather than 2.)

Comment: I am sorry. It's jsr_w not jsr_wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as `wide jsr`. `wide` can only be used with iload, fload, aload, lload, dload, istore, fstore, astore, lstore, dstore, ret, and iinc.

Technically, there's no such thing as `jsr_wide` either, but there is `jsr_w`, which is the wide variant of `jsr`. Likewise, there's also `goto` and `goto_w`.

So to answer the question, one of them is illegal and the other is the accepted way to use a larger jump offset for a `jsr` instruction.

Comment: Since the wide instruction modifies the next instruction, why didn't the designers of JVM design wide to be used with jsr? Thus, wide could modify jsr to accept a larger offset (just like the instructions you mentioned previously). Why did they introduce a whole new instruction: jsr_w?

Comment: Only the designers can answer that for sure, but there is a notable difference. All the instructions used with wide go from a 1 to 2 byte register index (or integer constant) whereas jsr and goto are going from 2 to 4 byte jump offsets. Maybe they wanted to keep jump offsets seperate, or maybe they thought it would be too complicated to have so many different formats used with wide.

Comment: The difference you mentioned has given me some insight into the design. Thank you so much. :)